# How to write async PHP code

Tags: php, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have some code that does something like this pseudocode:

```
Use CURL to get site1 into a variable
Use CURL to get site2 into a variable
Use CURL to get site3 into a variable
Use CURL to get site4 into a variable

Do lots of processing on each

Produce output

echo output
```

Currently this takes a long time occasionally.

I'd like to get the CURL bit to run in parallel so I can get things to speed up.

How do I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253791/asynchronous-parallel-http-requests-using-php-curl-multi

Comment: I'm not sure if this actually makes it faster, but you can try execute each curl in a separate thread.

Comment: You can try to open subprocesses using `proc_open()` in non-blocking mode. Sorry, but to lazy for a full answer

Comment: Maybe create 4 daemons to do the work: http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php parallel cURL requests.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know php does not support asynchronous IO.

But I can recommend on Node.js,which does support it and that's it's advantage. An additional advantage of Node.js is that you can use your form validations on client and on server side.

Comment: There are other solutions that have multithreading and what is really the strength of Node.js is actually ability to execute the script in a way it would be executed in the browser. So, basically, if you know JavaScript well engough, Node.js will be much easier to learn than eg. Python's Twisted.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future people, I'm actually planning to move some of the logic to the client, then use AJAX to request the PHP files with one CURL in each file. This way I can request all files at once, then use JS to parse and tidy up the results.